# Gradle incremental on different machines

Tags: gradle, incremental-build

We have multiple GitLab runners on different machines.

We broke our pipeline in multiple steps that are dependent and I see that gradle doesn't run incrementally.

For example, we have `build apk` and `upload apk to hockeyapp`. We always copy apk output from one step to another. However gradle still start building apk from scratch because upload needs it.

- How can I troubleshoot it?
- What folders to copy to make sure gradle runs incrementally?

We are on Gradle 4.x (4.1 and moving to 4.2)

Comment: It seems you need to copy `.gradle` from project root and `.gradle` from user home if dependencies are resolved every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should do this. You would probably need to copy over the `.gradle` directory from the root project, but I'm not sure this works too well and as expected. I guess you should instead use the new [Build Cache](https://guides.gradle.org/using-build-cache/) which sounds like being exactly what you need in your situation and is an official feature and does not involve some unsupported copying-around of build metadata.

Comment: So reading link about caches I need just copy `.gradle/caches`

Comment: @EugenMartynov no, that's not the way to work with build cache

Comment: I mean if I'm not yet ready to purchase cache serve from Gradle team

Comment: And I meant `$GRADLE_HOME\caches` folder

Comment: You don't need to purchase Gradle Enterprise, you can either use their Buildcache node for free or setup a completely custom Buildcache Server: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_setup_http_backend